# get value of input box by id stored in a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am wondering how to get the value of a input box by storing the `id` in a variable then fetching the value by that `id` variable. Here is what I have tried.

```
<script>
    var c=$("#inp").val();
    var temp = "i"+c;
    var obj = document.getElementById(temp).value;
    alert(obj);
</script>
```

> `<input type='text' class='form-control' value='$q6[$t2]' id='inp'>`/*php is used*/

Comment: What you have should work. Are you having any issues with it?

Comment: Could you post the Html too?

Comment: As long as your variable name doesn't start with a number, the code you have should work fine.

Comment: With a tag `<input id="i" />`, this will work.

Comment: Works fine with matching HTML: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/VLZEXd. Please post your HTML.

Comment: @rfornal Not with `div`, since `div` elements don't have `value` members. But with an `input`, as in the question, you're correct. It should work.

Comment: What value are you getting from the id i? Is the alert showing the incorrect value or just no value?

Comment: Sure you don't want info regarding a _checkbox_?

Comment: [works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/v0yobozt/)

Comment: i have posted the html code. my code doesnt return any value

Comment: So you're using the value of one textbox as part of a name of another textbox? Where is the HTML for the other textbox? What event is this code to be executed from? On page load? When the textbox changes?

Comment: This function is triggered by a normal button click event.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code works, but maybe you're doing something in the wrong order like putting the script before the element on the page. If your elements are in the following order, then it will work.

```html
<input type="text" id="i" value="asdf" />
<script>
    var temp = "i";
    var obj = document.getElementById(temp).value;
    alert(obj);
</script>
```

### edit

Based on your question's edits, given this input:

```
<input type='text' class='form-control' value='$q6[$t2]' id='inp'>
```

The value of c may not be what you think it is.

```
var c = $("#inp").val(); //equals $q6[$t2] exactly
```

By adding an i to the front of it, you get exactly that - `i$q6[$t2]` now the only way your script is going to work is if you have another element on the page with that ID.

```
<input type='text' id='i$q6[$t2]' value='output' />
```

I wonder is it really what you want to accomplish? If so, this snippet demonstrates it.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' class='form-control' value='$q6[$t2]' id='inp'>
<input type='text' id='i$q6[$t2]' value='output' />
<script>
    var c=$("#inp").val();
    var temp = "i"+c;
    var obj = document.getElementById(temp).value;
    alert(obj);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' class='form-control' value='test' id='inp'>
<br>
<input type='text' class='form-control' value='$q6[$t2]' id='itest'>
<script>
var inp = $("#inp");
function chng(){
    var c=$("#inp").val();
    var temp = "#"+"i"+c;
    var obj = $(temp).val();
    alert(obj);
}
chng();
inp.on("change", chng);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call `getElementById`, you get a live node. That means its properties will update dynamically as the element in the page is modified (resized, typed into, selected). However, if you copy the value in a variable, this stored value won't update when you type in the input. That might be the cause of your problem here.

You need to update that variable when the "change" event is triggered for the input.

```
var myVal = null;

document.getElementById(temp).addEventListener("change", function(e) {
    myVal = e.target.value;
    alert(e.target.value);
});
```